# How to replace all string in all columns using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In pandas, how do I replace `&amp;` with '&' from all columns where `&amp` could be in any position in a string?

For example, in column Title if there is a value 'Good `&amp;` bad', how do I replace it with 'Good & bad'?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How working `df.replace('&amp;','&', regex=True)` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True` for substrings replacement:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Good &amp; bad', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'Good &amp; bad'],
                   'B': range(5),
                   'C': ['Good &amp; bad'] * 5})

print (df)
                A  B               C
0  Good &amp; bad  0  Good &amp; bad
1              BB  1  Good &amp; bad
2              CC  2  Good &amp; bad
3              DD  3  Good &amp; bad
4  Good &amp; bad  4  Good &amp; bad

df = df.replace('&amp;','&', regex=True)
print (df)
            A  B           C
0  Good & bad  0  Good & bad
1          BB  1  Good & bad
2          CC  2  Good & bad
3          DD  3  Good & bad
4  Good & bad  4  Good & bad
```

If want replace only one column:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace('&amp;','&', regex=True)
print (df)
            A  B               C
0  Good & bad  0  Good &amp; bad
1          BB  1  Good &amp; bad
2          CC  2  Good &amp; bad
3          DD  3  Good &amp; bad
4  Good & bad  4  Good &amp; bad
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`df['Title'] = titanic_df['Title'].replace("&amp;", "&")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this also worked for me

```
df['A'] = [i.replace('&amp;','&') for i in list(df['A'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative:

```py
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('&amp;', '&'))
```

This has the advantage of also supporting type casting. For example if you assume that `df['B']` contains strings of the form `'[0]', '[5]', '[10]'`, etc., and you want to keep only the numerical values, you could do:

```py
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')))
```